# Change the Directory when Upload a file

Tags: python, flask

I would like to change the default location use by the browser when uploading a file.
I mean I have a website and when the client clic on upload file, I would like to point to a target directory (ie Downloads) instead of Desktop.

How can I do it ?
My website use Flask / Python

Comment: do you men upload to the server or download to the machine the browser is running on?

Comment: I mean to the uploading machine

Comment: No, that would be an extreme security hole so that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably impossible. It's the client who choose's where to save data not the server.

You'll need to know the computer's folders paths. And that's called Hacking wich is illegal.